# one2many contains one2many how to set the value

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to directly add the following model in onchange value

The data is from other models

*My model*

Class A:

```py
_name = 'budget.budget'
main_materials_list = fields.One2many(comodel_name='budget.main.material', inverse_name='budget_id', string=u'A')

@api.onchange('suite_series')
def onchange_suite_series(self):
    self.main_materials_list = self._materialValue()

def _materialValue(self):
    page = []
    for item in self.suite_series.main_material_ids:
        product_ids = []
        data = {
            'product_id':self.main_materials_list.product_ids
        }

        for val in item.product_id:
            product_item = {
                'product_id': val.product_id.id
            }
            product_ids.append((0, 0, product_item)) 

        data.update({'product_ids': product_ids})
        page.append((0, 0, data))
    return page

Class B:
    _name = 'budget.main.material'
    product_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='budget.material', inverse_name='main_id', string=u'B')

Class C:
    _name = 'budget.material'
    product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='product.product', string=u'C')
```

Using the above method, then the second one2many assignment is not successful!